# Grails how make AJAX send the object that is edited in the form from a template

Tags: javascript, ajax, templates, grails

I want to update a field in the edit-form when another field is changed.
When the field1 is changed an AJAX-script will call the controller that calculates a new value for field2 and then render the template that updates this field.
But the controller needs two values, one is the value of field1 and one is the object that is edited. I need it to make it possible to render the template.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( document ).on('change', '.availableCert', function ( event ){ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '${g.createLink( controller:'offerDetail', action:'updatePrice' )}',
                    data: {availableCert:this.value, id:this.id},
                    type: 'get'
                }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#updatePrice' ).html( data );     });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( document ).on('change', '.adjustPrice', function ( event ){ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '${g.createLink( controller:'offerDetail', action:'updatePrice' )}',
                    data: {adjustPrice:this.value, id:this.id},
                    type: 'get'
                }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#updatePrice' ).html( data );     });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( document ).on('change', '.volumeOffered', function ( event ){ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '${g.createLink( controller:'offerDetail', action:'updatePrice' )}',
                    data: {volumeOffered:this.value, id:this.id},
                    type: 'get'
                }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#updatePrice' ).html( data );     });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

part of the template:

```
        <g:select class="availableCert" name="availableCert" from="${offerDetail.availableCert}" value="${offerDetail.choosedCert}" />    
</td>        
<td> FSC: ${offerDetail.priceFSC}</td>
<td> UC: ${offerDetail.priceUC}</td>
<td> CW: ${offerDetail.priceCW}</td>
<td> PEFC: ${offerDetail.pricePEFC}</td>
<td>  
    EndPrice:    ${offerDetail.endPrice}
</td>
```

So when the controller wants to render this field he needs to have the object ${offerDetail} to make it possible for the template to render it.

I can't see how the javascript can retrieve this object. But it maybe much simpler than I can imagine or?

Controller code:

```
def updatePrice() {
   def OfferDetail od
    if (params.id != null){
       od = OfferDetail.get(params.id)
   }
    if (params.availableCert != null) {
       od.choosedCert = params.availableCert
   } else if (params.adjustPrice != null) {
       od.priceAdjust = params.adjustPrice.toBigDecimal()
   } else if (params.volumeOffered != null) {
       od.volumeOffered = params.volumeOffered
   } else {}
   render template: "offerDData", model: [offerDetail:od]
}
```

Comment: It's probably simpler to pass the id of the object then look it up in the action

Comment: Of course, that works. But I have problem with the rendering. It does not chow changes in the field as the data is changed in the controller. I have to make a refresh manually on the page to get the field updated. I also gave up having the field on second level template. But the page does not update even if the controller is told to do so. Look at the controller code above: The endprice is updated in the domainclass in beforeUpdate.

Comment: Try adding `od.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` before your render

Comment: Hmm, it didn't help. I also thought that the data of od is brought to the template by [offerDetail:od] so didn't think a save was necessary.

Comment: Are you sure any of your if/else if statements are being hit? maybe try some breakpoints or sys outs. Also you don't need to specify `if( params.availableCert != null)` you can just do `if (params.availableCert)` etc

Comment: I'm sure they are hit, I added a println on each if-block so I could see if they where hit. I also have a println in the domain that verifies the new endPrice. Could it some problem as it is in a template? This template is also rendered from the main edit-form like this: <g:render template="OfferDData" model="[offerDetail:offerDetail]"/>

Comment: Instead of rendering a template, as a test just try rendering a div with a single value e.g. `render { div ( od.choosedCert ) }`

Comment: Nothing happened with that either. Sure I do not need to edit the GSP when testing this last tip?

Comment: Assuming you changed the dropdown with class availableCert which will call the updatePrice action which in turn should have updated the updatePrice div you should see the choosedCert value appear in there. It may be worth adding the following to your ajax calls after the success block `,error: function( j, status, eThrown ) { console.log( 'Error ' + eThrown ) }` & keep the browser's javascript console open during your calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145203/discussion-between-mike-w-and-larand).

Comment: You said it! The div was lost when I removed the 2nd level template. So now it's working and I'm happy with that even though I don't understand why it didn't work when the controller rendered the template. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can streamline your approach with dropdowns and have a single javascript function to handle all dropdown changes e.g.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( document ).on('change', '.odChange', function ( event ){ 
            $.ajax({
                url: '${g.createLink( controller:'offerDetail', action:'updatePrice' )}',
                data: {  updateVal :this.value, 
                         dropDownId: this.id,
                         offerDetailId: od.id
                      },
                type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#updatePrice' ).html( data );     });
        });
    });
</script>

<g:select class="odChange" name="availableCert" from="${offerDetail.availableCert}" value="${offerDetail.choosedCert}" />
<g:select class="odChange" name="adjustPrice" from="${offerDetail.adjustPrice}" value="${offerDetail.adjustPrice}" />
<g:select class="odChange" name="volumeOffered" from="${offerDetail.volumeOffered}" value="${offerDetail.volumeOffered}" />
```

It's worth looking at other options for [data binding](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#dataBinding)

E.g. for now you could try:

```
def updatePrice() {
   def od = OfferDetail.get( params.offerDetailId )
   od."${params.dropDownId}" = params.updateVal
   od.save( flush: true, failOnError: true )
   render template: "offerDData", model: [offerDetail:od]
}
```

Using the above it's important that your gsp field names match up with your domain's field names